# Ionic 2 - how to prevent page changes on ion-slides by swipe gesture?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, pagination, ionic2

I saw the solution in many different sources for this, including Stack Overflow. This is working for me partially: I can't swipe to the left or right to switch the pages. That's fine ! But if the user click a button , keep the button pressed and swipe, this will cause pagination. (I just testing using Android)

The solution according with many sources is that one:

```
<ion-slides [options]="{onlyExternal: false}">
</ion-slides>
```

Let me illustrate this with screenshots...

[image]

If I swipe here, nothing will happen

Now, if I hold and swipe the red button, this will cause pagination.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way i do this is:

On my .ts file of the page i have a slide i do this

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: 'page.html'
})
export class Page{
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  contructor() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }

  nextSlide(){
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.slides.slideNext();
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }
}
```

And in your HTML you call the function on a button

```
<button ion-button block (tap)="nextSlide()">NEXT</button>
```

So when the page is beeing constructed i lock the swipe, and when someone click next/back i unlock the swipe, go to next slide and lock it back.

Hope it helps

Comment: Let me try ! I will let you know

Comment: I think is better use just this.slides.onlyExternal = true; instead of this.slides.lockSwipes(true). It block just external use, like touch or click and you not will do everytime lock and unlock

Comment: don't try to access dom in constructor. Use ionViewDidLoad or ngOnInit to access the html element.

Comment: Works perfect on Ionic 5 as well. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 11):

Since externalOnly isn't working in Ionic 4 anymore, i looked into the Swiper API documentation and saw that it changed to `allowTouchMove` now.

So: `<ion-slides [options]="{allowTouchMove:false}"`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve it is adding the `swiper-no-swiping` class:

Example:

```
<ion-slides #slides class="swiper-no-swiping">
...
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use the function ionViewDidLoad() because when you put the "this.slides.lockSwipes(true);"  in the constructor, the page havent load yet, try to do this.

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onlyExternal` option. You can access it by ViewChild.

```js
@ViewChild('slider') slider: Slides;

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.slider.onlyExternal = true;
  this.slider.paginationClickable = false;
}

nextSlide() {
  this.slider.slideNext();
}
```

```html
<ion-slides pager #slider>
  ...
</ion-slides>
```

You can call `nextSlide()` e.g. by button within slide.

Update: `paginationClickable` does not work. :/

Currently this is the best solution to really control the behavior.

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.slider.lockSwipes(true);
}

nextSlide() {
  this.slider.lockSwipes(false);
  this.slider.slideNext();
  this.slider.lockSwipes(true);
}
```